# Blog post not showing in specific categories - BeTheme

Tags: wordpress

I have categorized every blogpost into specific category on my blog, yet whenever I try to access a particular category page, I am not able to see posts specific to it.

I am having the following 6 categories:

1. Mixed
2. Relationships
3. Entrepreneurship
4. Blogging
5. Health and Lifestyle
6. Technology

Now, let us assume I try to open **Relationships** category, so my URL will be something like: [An example of my URL while opening a particular category page](http://whereispillmythoughts.com/relationships/)

In here, I want only the posts which belong to **'Relationships'** to get visible to my users, however it is not happening.

What the users see is - **a complete list of blog posts**

Any way to resolve this issue? Is there any way wherein I can simply call blog posts as per the category chosen?

Looking forward to some assistance on this issue.

Regards!

Comment: Make sure you are using `archive.php` file

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit @amit. I failed to understand what you meant.

Comment: Please check your theme's folder for `archive.php` file. Is it exist or not?

Comment: I got into this: 
public_html >> wp-content >> themes >> Betheme (current theme that is installed on my blog). 

Couldn't find 'archive.php' there. 

Tried searching the entire CPanel, but it still wasn't there except for the older themes  (ones which came preinstalled on WordPress).